# Date field value changing from client side to server side

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, date

I have an AJAX call to the controller and I am using JSON.stringify to send the data to the controller action. My issue is the date field which on the client side is EDT(my local time) is being converted to GMT on the server side. Is there something I should do for it to remain in EDT.

This is my code :

```
var EndDate= new Date($('#TBEndDateTime').val().trim()); //EndDate= Sat Aug 26 2017 12:54:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time) (Console value while debugging)

var objEnd = JSON.stringify({
    EndDate: EndDate
})

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Close/EndFunction",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json",
    data: objEnd,
    cache: false,
    success: function (result) {

    }
});
```

And on the server side

```
 public JsonResult EndFunction(FunctionEnd endFunction) //EndDate 2017-08-26T16:54:00.000Z
 {

 }
```

Why is there a discrepancy and how can it be resolved?

EDIT 1:
Using .toISOstring does not work either.

```
var EndOn = new Date($('#TBEndDateTime').val().trim()).toISOString(); //EndDate 2017-08-26T16:54:00.000Z
```

Comment: Can't you just use the dates in UTC and then make the proper conversions?

Comment: new Date(val).toISOString() might be helpful.

Comment: @axel.michel Doesn't ISOstring() convert it to GMT again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is avoid stringify from manipulating your code. This is where ISOstring() as @axel.michel pointed out will help you. Also you can use the getTimezoneOffset() to get the timezone right.

```
var EndDate= new Date($('#TBEndDateTime').val().trim());
EndDate= new Date(EndDate.getTime() - (EndDate.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000)).toISOString();
```